# Table of Contents is positioned too low Latex

Tags: table-of-contents, positioning

For some reason my table of contents and my list of figures are centered on the page whereas I want them to start at the very top. How do i fix this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Please provide a small, yet complete document demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX - LaTeX! [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.